# Changing a Nitwit in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How to change a Nitwit villager into a Zombie villager? In minecraft Wiki, Nitwit villager can be changed into Zombie villager , then into employable villager when cured. The Wki does not mention how. My question is how to do this?

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: To the person who edited this question for Java Edition, why can you assume its for Java?

Comment: @Penguin They had no choice. The system won’t allow for no tags on a post. Leaving it with the incorrect tag `virtual-villagers-2` would be even worse.

Answer (score 2):

The [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Villager) states:

> If any type of zombie kills a villager, there is a chance for the villager to transform into a zombie villager. If the villager has previously been traded with, this zombie villager does not despawn when the player moves far away from it.
>
> Chance for villagers killed by zombies to turn into zombie villagers
>
> Difficulty / Chance
>
> - Easy 0%
> - Normal   50%
> - Hard 100%

So firstly, for the chance that the villager will even be converted to begin with is dependent on the difficulty you are playing (I believe this is a "horde" gameplay mechanic - on Easy, you won't be overrun by Zombies, on Hard, you will be). So if you want your Nitwit to be converted, you must be playing on *at least* Normal difficulty.

In order to [Cure](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Villager#Curing) the Villager, after it has been converted:

> Zombie villagers can be cured by using a golden apple (regular) on them while they are under the effects of Weakness, which can be applied by:
>
> - A splash potion of Weakness thrown by the player or a witch.
> - An area effect cloud of Weakness from a lingering potion or a creeper exploding while under the Weakness effect.
> - A tipped arrow.

### However...

I don't believe that a Nitwit can be "reassigned" into an average villager (from the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Villager#Curing); emphasis mine):

> When the conversion time reaches 0, the zombie villager transforms into a villager. In Java Edition, if the villager is not locked to a profession (i.e by trading with it once), the villager is unemployed **unless it was a nitwit, in which case it remains a nitwit;** if it was locked to a profession, it keeps both that profession and trades. **However, in Bedrock Edition, the villager keeps whatever profession it had while it was a zombie and cannot be reassigned.**

I'm not sure if this means that Nitwits transform into regular villagers after being cured, if you are playing on Bedrock Edition.